# Parsing expressions with subexpressions in ANTLR

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

I am trying to parse recursive expressions in ANTLR such as:

```
(a + (b + C))
```

or

```
((a + b))
```

I read this supposed solution:
[ANTLR Grammar for expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452729/antlr-grammar-for-expressions)

However when I try to create a rule such as:

```
ParenthesisExpression: '(' (ParenthesisExpression | Expression) ')';
```

ANTLR complains that "Rule ParenthesisExpression is left-recursive".

How can I parse expressions that can have within themselves, subexpressions of the same form?

Comment: Don't look to closely to the post you linked to: it is littered with false information, and the grammar the OP posted doesn't even come close to being a valid ANTLR grammar. I am amazed that you managed to dig up that old (incorrect!) Q&A, while there are quite some other ones posted more recently (like: [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931307/antlr-is-there-a-simple-example/1932664#1932664), or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396080/antlr-3-3-c-tutorials/4397799#4397799) geared towards C#).

Comment: Or this one: http://bkiers.blogspot.com/2011/03/2-introduction-to-antlr.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
parse
  :  addExp EOF
  ;

addExp
  :  multExp (('+' | '-') multExp)*
  ;

multExp
  :  atom (('*' | '/') atom)*
  ;

atom
  :  ID
  |  '(' addExp ')'
  ;

ID    : 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z';
```

The closer you come to the `atom` rule, the higher the precedence: so `+` and `-` have the lowest precedence, followed by `*` and `/`, and lastly, `ID` and `( ... )` have the highest precedence.

---

It parses the input:

```
((a / b)) - x
```

as follows:

[image]

---

and the input:

```
(a * (b + C))
```

is parsed like:

[image]