# ANTLR rule rewrite to nested tree

Tags: parsing, url-rewriting, antlr, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to make a rule that will rewrite into a nested tree (similar to a binary tree).

For example:

```
a + b + c + d;
```

Would parse to a tree like `( ( (a + b) + c) + d)`. Basically each root node would have three children (LHS '+' RHS) where LHS could be more nested nodes.

I attempted some things like:

```
rule: lhs '+' ID;
lhs: ID | rule;
```

and

```
rule
    : rule '+' ID
    | ID '+' ID;
```

(with some tree rewrites) but they all gave me an error about it being left-recursive. I'm not sure how to solve this without some type of recursion.

EDIT: My latest attempt recurses on the right side which gives the reverse of what I want:

`rule:

        ID (op='+' rule)?

        -> {op == null}? ID

        -> ^(BinaryExpression<node=MyBinaryExpression> ID $op rule)`

Gives `(a + (b + (c + d) ) )`

Comment: You have to use nested expressions since ANTLR is LL(*). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452729/antlr-grammar-for-expressions?rq=1). Or you can do it in the tree parser, which may be easier/faster depending on your grammar.

Comment: If `a + b` are all child nodes, what is the root? Why don't you want the operator as root?

Comment: The root node is an imaginary node. The tree structure is part of the requirements I'm working within.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The follow grammar:

```
grammar T;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  BinaryExpression;
}

parse
 : expr ';' EOF -> expr
 ;

expr
 : (atom -> atom) (ADD a=atom -> ^(BinaryExpression $expr ADD $a))*
 ;

atom
 : ID
 | NUM
 | '(' expr ')'
 ;

ADD   : '+';
NUM   : '0'..'9'+;
ID    : 'a'..'z'+;
SPACE : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {skip();};
```

parses your input `"a + b + c + d;"` as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
rule: ID '+' rule | ID;
```

?

Comment: Yes, that gives me a tree that's backwards to what I want:

`(a + (b + (c + d) ) )`