# caret prefix instead of postfix in antlr

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I know what the caret postfix means in antlr(ie. make root) but what about when the caret is the prefix as in the following grammar I have been reading(this grammar is brand new and done by a new team learning antlr)....

```
selectClause
    : SELECT resultList -> ^(SELECT_CLAUSE resultList) 
    ;


fromClause
    : FROM tableList -> ^(FROM_CLAUSE tableList) 
    ;
```

Also, I know what => means but what about the -> ?  What does -> imply?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `^` is used as an inline tree operator, indicating a certain token should become the root of the tree.

For example, the rule:

```
p : A B^ C;
```

creates the following AST:

```
  B
 / \
A   C
```

There's another way to create an AST which is using a *rewrite rule*. A *rewrite rule* is placed after (or at the right of) an alternative of a parser rule. You start a *rewrite rule* with an "arrow", `->`, followed by the rules/tokens you want to be in the AST.

Take the previous rule:

```
p : A B C;
```

and you want to reverse the tokens, but keep the ASST "flat" (no root node). THis can be done using the following *rewrite rule*:

```
p : A B C -> C B A;
```

And if you want to create an AST similar to `p : A B^ C;`, you start your *rewrite rule* with `^( ... )` where the first token/rule inside the parenthesis will become the root node. So the rule:

```
p : A B C -> ^(B A C);
```

produces the same AST as `p : A B^ C;`.

---

#### Related:

- [Tree construction](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Tree+construction)
- [How to output the AST built using ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931346/how-to-output-the-ast-built-using-antlr)