# what does '^' after some token names in antlr do?

Tags: regex, antlr, antlr3

this is part of the https://github.com/monperrus/pascal3g/blob/master/pascal3g.g file. I have searched everywhere in the antlr4 documentation, but still don't know what the '^' sign do. Is this a sign for older versions of antlr?

```
usesUnitsPart
    : USES^ identifierList SEMI!
    ;

labelDeclarationPart
    : LABEL^ label ( COMMA! label )* SEMI!
    ;
```

I was asked to modify my question -- this is a sign in antlr3, and it was removed from antlr4. This is a difference of the two versions.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but in a regex, depending on the context, `^`  means `beginning of a string` or `different from`

Comment: This is only used in Antlr3, _not_ Antlr4!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [ANTLR By Example: Part 3: Parsing](http://www.alittlemadness.com/2006/06/19/antlr-by-example-part-3-parsing/):

> We guide the AST construction using postfix annotations on the tokens in our parser rules. The following annotations are available:
>
> - no annotation: a token without an annotation becomes a leaf node in the tree
> - ^: a token annotated with a carat becomes a sub-expression root
> - !: a token annotated with an exclamation point is not included in the tree

(Which also covers the `!`s in your example that you hadn't yet asked about)

Comment: Thanks! and your link may helpful for newbies like me!

Answer (score 1):

```
The ^ is used as an inline tree operator, indicating a certain token should become the root of the tree
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know on which page of The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference has mentioned this?

Comment: Check it here: https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Tree+construction . You may also want to check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365781/caret-prefix-instead-of-postfix-in-antlr?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, gl :)